RequestFilterValve constantly throws an error on startup in Apache Tomcat 10.1.28
There is a vulnerability in Tomcat 10.1.28 where inserting a semicolon in the url path will allow seeing the contents of a file.  For example, the URL:  mysite.com/myapp;/thisfile.config  will display the contents of thisfile.config, because of the semicolon.  The workaround is supposed to be to use RequestFilterValve in the server.xml file, and filter out any URL with a semicolon.  However I cannot get this to work.
I have put the following code in server.xml in the <hosts> section
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve" 
          deny="^.*;.*$" 
          denyStatus="403" />
</Host>

Actually, it doesn't matter what I put in for parameters.  As soon as the className is org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve,  Tomcat will not load and gives the following errors:

WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.parseServerXml Unable to load server configuration from [/opt/myapp/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/conf/server.xml]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/opt/myapp/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/conf/server.xml; lineNumber: 161; columnNumber: 35; Error at line [161] column [35]: [null]
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Cannot start server, server instance is not configured

The line and column are always the character after the closing \> .
Any suggestions or ideas?  Thanks!
